# Динамическая подгрузка информации на странице(таблице)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Есть таблица, нужно сделать так чтобы при выборе определенной категории ("Самовывоз", "Доставка курьером"), нужно в соседнее поля динамически подгружать информацию об этой категории. И прибавлять к общей сумме заказа стоимость доставки(стоимость доставки зависит от выбранного вида доставки). Пока могу только выводить информацию. Таблица:

```
...
<td colspan ="2">
    <div class="showDelInfo"></div>
</td>

<td colspan ="4">
    <select class="delivery-select form-control">
        <option data-del-id="1">Самовывоз</option>
        <option data-del-id="3">Доставка курьером</option>
    </select>
</td>
....
```

И скрипт обработчик:

```
var delId = $(this).find('option:selected').data('del-id');

$.ajax({
     url: '/engine/myFunctions/myFunctions.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {action:'changeTable', 'delId':delId},
     success: function(html){
         $('.showDelInfo').html(html).show();
     }
});
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы получить стоимость доставки и прибавить ее к общей сумме и динамически поменять общую стоимость на всей странице(в трех местах)?

```
<p class="text-right">Общая сумма: <?=$_SESSION['res']?> р.</p>
```

Comment: Можно к `select > option` добавить атрибут `del-price` и складывать или вычитать значения, а в php передавать массив выбранных услуг и только в нём считать итоговую цену (для оплаты)

Comment: Забыл сказать, что в js нужна переменная с итоговой ценой, чтобы использовать её в качестве значения в трёх местах